# How to restrict the area for operation in python pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I`d like to qualify my dropna option within the first 3 rows of the dataframe. The original dataframe is:

```
     A  C
0  0.0  0
1  NaN  1
2  2.0  2
3  3.0  3
4  NaN  4
5  5.0  5
6  6.0  6
```

And I would love to see:

```
     A  C
0  0.0  0
2  2.0  2
3  3.0  3
4  NaN  4
5  5.0  5
6  6.0  6
```

With only the row indexed 1 removed. **Is it possible to make it within just *one* line of code?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
In [594]: df[df.notnull().all(1) | (df.index > 3)]
Out[594]:
     A  C
0  0.0  0
2  2.0  2
3  3.0  3
4  NaN  4
5  5.0  5
6  6.0  6
```

Comment: Yes that`s truly helpful. Thank you !